# Join three tables A, B, C and return common in A in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to join below three tables A, B, C and return only common(shaded) part of table A

```
A
-------
ID, Name

B
-------
ID, ORG

C
--------
ID, DEP
```

[image]

Please anyone provide simple join query

Comment: You should really provide more information about what the tables look like.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want rows from `a` whose `id` can be foud in either `b` or `c`.

This sounds like two `exists` subquery:

```
select a.*
from a
where 
    exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id)
    or exists (select 1 from c where c.id = a.id)
```

If you also want columns from tables b or c, you can use two `left joins` instead, with a `where` condition that ensures that at least one of the joins did succeed:

```
select a.*, b.org, c.dept
from a
left join b on b.id = a.id
left join c on c.id = a.id
where b.id is not null or c.id is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `left join` starting with `A` and then some filtering:

```
select . . .
from a left join
     b
     on . . .  left join
     c
     on . . .
where b.? is not null or c.? is not null;
```

The `?` are either columns used in the `join`s or primary keys on the respective tables.